# Architectural Analysis: when all registers are used by by the subroutine, what must the machine do before jumping to the new subroutine?

Tags: analysis, subroutine

In OO programming we organize small chunks of frequently run code into methods. This reduces the total amount of code compared to copy/past (among other advantages). In assembly and machine languages these reusable chunks are called subroutines.

Often the original routine and the subroutine called make use of many or most of the available registers.

When all registers are used up by the subroutine,
explain what the machine must do before jumping to the new subroutine.

Comment: this smells very strongly of homework

Answer (score 1):

So the callee registers are pushed as part of call sequence and restored after subroutine exits as part of return sequence. This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) provides further details on this.

Comment: wow.. thanks Neera for the answer and link!! I'll go check it out.